# Convert Label into int in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a table that I fill with one Repeater and one SQL query. Then, I want to color one of the columns depend of the result of one operation. But the problem is that I want to compare one column with another(more specific, **intColumn1 <= intColumn2**), but I cannot convert the Label into Int (both columns are ints)
I have this code:

```
 Label lblStock = (Label)rptItem.FindControl("lblStockOLD");
 int intStock = Convert.ToInt32(lblStock.Text);
```

And I try to `lblStock` without "`.Text`" in the convertion. The display error is this:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

What can I do?

Comment: What is the value of lblStock.Text?

Comment: I think this is the right way. Your label must contains a value that you can't convert in integer (string empty for example)

Comment: We need to know the exact text you convert to be able to reproduce. Standard culprits are: culture/number formatting (i.e. separators) and non-printable characters so check for those.

Comment: Have you tried to use the debugger to see what the value of `lblStock` is? From the looks of it, either lblStock doesnt have any Text or its not a string with numbers only.

Comment: @EylM It must be a number, in this case is 0.

Comment: @Jawad The first value is 0.

Comment: See: [Tutorial: Learn to debug C# code using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2019) and also [Walkthrough: Debugging a Web Form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/walkthrough-debugging-a-web-form?view=vs-2019). Set a breakpoint on the second line and watch contents of `lblStock.Text`. Does it contain the expected string `"0"`?

Comment: Your question is unclear: do you get this error with `Convert.ToInt32(lblStock.Text)`?  Why are you trying to remove the `.Text` part?

Comment: @Amy I had to try everything, but added `.Text` later.

Comment: @RobertoLopez Okay, having `.Text` there is correct, so it is unclear what the issue is now.  If that label contains `"0"` then your code should work.  If it doesn't, we need to know the actual value contained in the label.

Comment: The query has like 111,000 rows, I find that some of them has NULL data. That is the error I think. Thank you everyone.

Comment: @RobertoLopez .... that sounds like relevant info.  What "111,000 rows" are you talking about?  What query? The way your question is written implies you have *one* label.  This isn't answerable as is.

Comment: [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=netframework-4.8#System_Convert_ToInt32_System_String_) for `Convert.ToInt32` says that the method will throw a `FormatException` if the *"value does not consist of an optional sign followed by a sequence of digits (0 through 9)."* So that is most likely the case. Set a breakpoint on that line and examine the value of `lblStock.Text` in the debugger.

Comment: You can use the [`int.TryParse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8#System_Int32_TryParse_System_String_System_Int32__) method instead, which attempts to set the `out` parameter to the converted value of the `string` parameter, and returns a `bool` indicating success. If you want your variable to be `0` on failure, then you don't even have to worry about the return value, since `0` is the default value of an `int`, which is what the method sets it to on failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer to approach this problem by calculating the difference in int BEFORE you bind the data to the repeater.  However if you have to get the string out of the label and convert it back to int, and the field is nullable, you must do null checking first.

```
Label lblStock = (Label)rptItem.FindControl("lblStockOLD");
//assume intStock is null and make sure you check for intStock.HasValue later.
int? intStock = null;
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lblStock.Text)) {
    intStock = Convert.ToInt32(lblStock.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"Input string was not in a correct format." means that what your trying to convert to an int is not a correct int. You could use `Int.TryParse` for better error handling. if the `.Text` contains a correct integer value it should be able to convert it. Also keep in mind that if you run the code before filling up the label it will also give errors .